# What Javascript types can have properties?

Tags: javascript

Given var x, what is the best  way to determine if x can have properties? Can I just do

> if(x instanceof Object)

Is that sufficient to ensure that x can have properties or do I need to check for anything else? I know primitives can't have properties but is there anything else? I've been going through checking various types:

```
var a = false;
a.foo = "bar";
console.log(a["foo"]);
// Logs undefined

var b = "b";
b.foo = "bar";
console.log(b["foo"]);
// Logs undefined

var c = new Array(1,2,3);
c.foo = "bar";
console.log(c["foo"]);
// Logs bar

var d = new Object();
d.foo = "bar";
console.log(d["foo"]);
// Logs bar

var e = new RegExp("");
e.foo = "foo";
console.log(e["bar"]);
// Logs bar

var f = new Number(1);
f.foo = "bar";
console.log(f["foo"]);
// Logs bar

var g = function(){};
g.foo = "bar";
console.log(g["foo"]);
// Logs bar
```

etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is sufficient. Note: `String` can also accept properties, which you are not checking for:

```
var a = new String("hello");
a.foo = "bar";
```

But since `String instanceof Object == true` you should be fine.

For fun, try this (it works, since `/x/ instanceof Object == true`):

```
var x = /hello/;
x.foo = "bar";
```

Another note: your `instanceof` check will catch this, but I want you to be aware that while normal a javascript `function` is an `Object`, a closure `(function() { })()` is not *necessarily* an `Object`, but it *might* be depending on the value it returns.

Hope that helps.

-tjw

Comment: Your definition of a "closure" is really an anonymous function expression that is immediately executed instead of being assigned to anything - and **it is an object**, but *the return value may not be*.  Your definition is incorrect because all function expressions are closures, whether being immediately executed or not.  See http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/.

Comment: It's a closure that happens to be anonymous. Anonymous simply means it isn't bound to a name, closure means that it retains references to variables in its dynamic scope (that is, at run-time). `var x = (function (x) { })(1)` is also a closure, but it is not anonymous. Also, you're wrong about calling this an object. Neither of these are objects, they are simply the type of whatever value is returned from the routine. Calling a self-invoking function an `Object` is like calling the body of an `if` statement an object; it makes no sense for the same reason.

Comment: I suggest you take a good look at the ECMA-262 specification - you seem to be a bit confused about it.  All functions are Objects with an internal *[[Call]]* attribute. There's no such thing as a self-invoking function; in your example you are invoking the function expression just as you would any named function.  They're commonly referred self-invoking or self-executing, and I've even used the term myself, but the term isn't an accurate one.

Comment: Also, the function you wrote in your comment is still anonymous - it doesn't have a name.  My point was that all functions are objects *and* closures and your statement was incorrect.  If you're stubborn enough to tell me I'm wrong without reading the spec or the reference I pointed you towards, then that's up to you.  I'm just trying to help :-)

Comment: @AndyE your confusing each other with your definitions. A self invoking function is a _function_ and therefore an _object_. The expression of a self invoking function is whatever the _return_ object is. Please make a _distinction_ between a self-invoking _function_ and the _expression_ that is a self-invoking function. Again your original statement "closure `(function() { })()` is not _necessarily_ an object" is wrong because the "closure" is the _function_. The "closure" is _not_ the expression. You guys need to normalise your choice of words.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a JavaScript object first like so:

```
<script>
var foo = {};
foo.bar = 'test';
console.log(foo.bar);
</script>
```

Vars a and b are just plain ole variables. The `var foo = {};` bit is similar to a builtin object called foo and you created an instance like `var bar = new foo();`

Comment: Heh..."ole" as in "old," "common," "plain," etc. :) Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Umm...I answered the question from my understanding and my example does work. You can't turn regular string variables into objects. You are wrong.